# How to parameterize IN clause in SQL Query to use in JMETER

Tags: sql, jmeter, parameter-passing, prepared-statement

I need to parametrize a SQL Query to use in JMETER such that every time it triggers, a random value is picked from the list of values to be used in IN clause.

Parent Query - Select * from Employee where Emp_Id in ( 3,9,11,12,13) and Dept_Name in('HR',IT','Admin','Audit')

Post the Parameterization when i trigger the Query through JDBC Request the request run for different user needs to have random selection made.
Ex:
Query 1 should be like - Select * from Employee where Emp_Id in ( 3,9) and Dept_Name in('HR',IT')

Query 2 should be like - Select * from Employee where Emp_Id in ( 11,12,13) and Dept_Name in('HR',IT','Admin')

I am trying to use CSV Data Set Config but not able to achieve the above output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I would recommend reconsidering your whole approach because tests needs to be **[repeatable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeatability)**, if you need to check all the possible combinations of the emp and dept IDs - go for [pairwise testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-pairs_testing), store the generated queries in the CSV file and parameterize the queries using [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config).

If you **still** want to make the number of arguments absolutely random you can go for the following approach:

1. Add [User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables) to your Test Plan and define the following variables there:

   ```
   Emp_Id=3,9,11,12,13
   Dept_Name=HR,IT,Admin
   ```
2. Amend your query to include JMeter's [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like:

   ```
   Select * from Employee where Emp_Id in (${__groovy(def values = vars.get('Emp_Id').split('\,').collect(); values.shuffle(); values.take(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextInt(1\,values.size())).join('\,'),)}) and Dept_Name in(${__groovy(def values = vars.get('Dept_Name').split('\,').collect{value -> "'" + value + "'"}; values.shuffle(); values.take(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextInt(1\,values.size())).join('\,'),)})
   ```

Demo:

[image]